# How combine enable popovers everywhere AND use container: 'body' option?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

I noticed my Bootstrap 5 popovers are missing the arrow and I believe it's caused by the parent element interfearing somehow.
The docs are kind enough to offer help by showing me how to use the container: 'body' option - on ONE item. I need to apply that to all at once. How would I do that?

I'm using codeKit3 to bundle everything. The import statement looks like this (working):

```
//  Bootstrap components
import '@popperjs/core/lib/index.js'
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js'
```

This is the html I'm using:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <i class="fas fa-calendar-day"></i> 24-h
  </div>
  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        högsta temp
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <span class="card-value" id="min-rh-24h">24</span><span class="card-value">°C</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="top"
          title="Ytterligare information"
          data-bs-content="Some sample text right here"><i
            class="fas fa-info" id="maxCelsius24hInfo"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">
        lägsta temp
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <span class="card-value" id="min-rh-24h">12</span><span class="card-value">°C</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
        <a href="#" data-bs-toggle="popover" data-bs-placement="top" data-container="body"
          title="Ytterligare information"
          data-bs-content="Some other sample data right here"><i
            class="fas fa-info" id="minCelsius24hInfo"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Code snippet from Bootstrap 5 docs:

```
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})
```

The only way the documentation shows how to implement the container option is like this:

```
var popover = new bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('.example-popover'), {
  container: 'body'
})
```

I need to use the `container: 'body'` option in the first example (the one with `map()`). How would I do that?

Thank you!

Comment: It is the same method call in both cases, so just add the second parameter the exact same way ...? `return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl, { container: 'body' })`

Comment: @CBroe Thank you! Ok, that was easy - as always when you know the right answer :) Unfortunately it did not fix the issue. It doesn't give me any console errors so I guess the code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
var popover = new bootstrap.Popover(document.querySelector('.example-popover'), {
  container: 'body'
})

var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl)
})
```

This does the same basic method call `new bootstrap.Popover(...)` in both places - so just add the second parameter in the second version, exactly the same as it was used in the first one:

```
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
    return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl, { container: 'body' })
})
```

Comment: Can you please check this. If you can help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70966879/bootstrap-5-dropdown-position-relatively-to-body-with-boundary-option